# What is PrintStackTrace() method and how is it Different from the Get Method?

Tags: java, netbeans

Im having a Problem Understanding what is `PrintStackTrace()` and How is it different from the `Get()` Method.

Comment: I think you need to give more context on which `PrintStackTrace()` and `Get()` methods you are talking about.

Comment: In addition, what have you done so far to solve the problem? Have you read the documentation for the methods? What do you *think* they do? Have you tried calling them? Can you provide more detail on how their documented or observed behavior is confusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrintStackTrace() PrintStackTrace()  will write directly to the console.
Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream. This method prints a stack trace for this Throwable object on the error output stream that is the value of the field System.err. The first line of output contains the result of the toString() method for this object. Remaining lines represent data previously recorded by the method fillInStackTrace(). The format of this information depends on the implementation, but the following example may be regarded as typical.

get

That will give you the stacktrace[] elements and printed the stacktrace in System.err